# how to get callback response using twitter sdk in angular2?

Tags: angular, twitter

How to share some content on twitter using angular2 with callback function.
I have found this piece of code without callback function

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.hello.com.br/blog/" data-via="@pardeepjain_90" data-lang="pt" data-text="XYZ">Share Twitter</a>
```

but I want some callback after posting successfully , how to do this ? 
working code in JS

http://jsfiddle.net/pinceladasdaweb/4ZEFF/

Comment: you should explain some more what you want.

Comment: @Roninio i just want to share some content on twitter on button click in angular2 code but i want some callback for the assurance of posting that content successfully. is it possible in twitter if so than how ?